# create a child node via api

Tags: entities, 9

Running Drupal 9.3, I have two content types, job and and Job detail. Every job has many job details.

Lets say i created a job with node ID of 5. I have a field in job detail called "field_job_id" that will take the node ID of the parent, in this case "5".

When creating a job detail node, i have tried inputting the node ID as a int, as a string and nothing works.

```
    "_links": {
    "type": {
      "href": "https://domain.com/rest/type/node/job_detail"
    }
  },
  "title": [
    {
      "value": filename
    }
  ],
  "field_job_id": [
    {
      "value": jobTitle
    }
  ],
  "field_document_type": [
    {
      "value": "PDF"
    }
  ],
  "field_author": [
    {
      "value": author
    }
  ],
  "field_remediation_cost": [
    {
      "value": "0"
    }
  ]
})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/hal+json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic HDHBdbdb83hcn8echw8fy389hfeuivbwe'
}
```

The node get posted but the field that should display the parent node is blank every time. Is there something i am doing wrong?

Comment: ok...so it seems I need to add a "relationships" field to this but not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: Is job id an entity reference? Should it be target_id instead?

Comment: @kevin Yes. it is a entity reference. I am very new to rest api so i will try that

Comment: @Kevin I could not for the life of me get a relationship into a rest api. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALLY figured it out. since I am dealing with a entity ref, that being "field_job_id" I had to add a field

```
  "field_job_id":[{"target_id":8}],
```

with 8 being the node of the job it is referencing